# Is it a good idea to use a raspberry pi to implement a backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, raspberry-pi, backend, raspberry-pi3

I am looking for a good option to implement my backend, it is to take inventory and generate reports, are registered company can carry out between 1,000 and 2,000 readings and item registration, at this moment there are 20 registered companies, which translates into an average of 40000 daily requests, I was looking for alternatives in the cloud but it makes me very expensive to be an MVP, so I'm thinking of using a raspberry pi to build my backend.

The technologies used to develop this backend are:

- Typescript (Backend)
- Mysql (Database)
- React (Frontend)
- Docker-compose

I would like to know if it can support this amount of requests.For more clarity I share the following graph:
[image]

Comment: I do use a Pi for a wiki at home and that includes Tomcat and a MySQL database running on it as well. However, do not store important data (such as the database) in the SD card. Attach a USB drive for it instead. That instantly increases the cost of the setup by $40-$70. Alternatively, I pay $7/month for a whole server (25 GB ssd, 1GB ram) at digitalocean, and that comes with an automated weekly backup.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a valid question. Thing is: there is no universal "good" in IT. It is always about trade offs. Meaning: it really depends on your requirements. We can't assess for example the cost of your service going down. What does one day of full outage cost you? And how many minutes/hours/days of outage would your customers accept? And personally, I can't assess the durability/robustness of a Pi based solution ... as your risk includes that assessment "cost of outage", but also "likelihood of outage".

Comment: If we would be talking about a really low-cost prototype, then sure, why not. But 40K requests from 20 real customers ... hrmrmrmrmr. As said, it might be all fine ... but you should double check with other people. If you would be fired if that service goes down, you better make sure that you don't make this decision alone.

Comment: have you tried this idea on project? I am also thinking like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a raspberry PI would be fun as a side project, I would not be using it to implement a real backend.

Using DynamoDB as a database and S3 as your hosting platform for your frontend would be extremely cost effective, not to mention highly available and durable.

40k requests per day is 1 request every two seconds which DynamoDB can handle in it's free tier with ease.

S3 also has a free tier for the first year and would have minimal to no cost thereafter.